# Can I install safely Ubuntu on my Mac?

Tags: 12.04, mac

I have some questions related with Ubuntu. I have an iMac, with OS X Lion and Windows 7 installed. So, can I install Ubuntu alongside Mac and Windows without any problems? Can I resize my Mac's partition later?

Also, my keyboard doesn't seems to work... :/

My iMac is a Late 2009 with 4 GB of RAM.

Comment: I'm not a MAC user, but as for resizing your partition, do try downloading Gparted.

Comment: Resizing is no problem, I know how to do it. What I want to say is what can happen if I resize after installing Ubuntu.

Comment: depending on big you hard drive is and how much space you have I would just give it 50-60 gb which is more than enough seeing how it needs less than 20 gb, that's with live cd, with wubi, even less.

Comment: The problem related with installing now Ubuntu, is that Mac use EFI instead of BIOS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This sonuds like a good reason to take caution when installing on a Mac.

From https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting

> Caution for Mac owners
>
> From Ubuntu 11.04 onwards (x86_64 only), the ISO CD supports UEFI
>   booting and the Ubuntu installer will try to set up the bootloader for
>   (U)EFI boot. But the installer formats the EFI System Partition to
>   FAT16 (even if the filesystem is non-empty) and also uses efibootmgr,
>   therefore Intel Macs may fail to boot due to corrupted firmware. This
>   feature is not recommended on Mac models because it can corrupt the
>   firmware. You will need to reflash the firmware to repair it.
>
> On Macs use only the Mac alternate ISO CD

Mactel support pages, list what works and what dosen't and version used for mac type, https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MactelSupportTeam/CommunityHelpPages

Mac triple boot how-to https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacBook/TripleBoot

Comment: I have a question: as there are no custom ISOs for Ubuntu 12.04, can I avoid the formatting of the UEFI partition, for example, booting with BIOS?

Comment: Hmm, looks like they aren't listed on the main site, and the link on the cdimage site is down, so here is a mirror link http://mirror.iawnet.sandia.gov/ubuntu-iso/DVDs/ubuntu/12.04/release/

Comment: OK, this ISO works. This is what I most like about Ubuntu: its community. Thanks! :)

Comment: Update: [This critical bug was fixed.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-release-notes/+bug/774089) (A while ago, actually. No version of Ubuntu after 11.04 was affected; the UEFIBooting page has been [updated to reflect this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting#Caution_for_Mac_owners).) Related: [This question about whether or not this bug is still an issue.](http://askubuntu.com/q/333303/22949) We probably should dupe one to the other. On the other hand, this question, and this answer, are a bit broader, pertaining to compatibility also.