# Installing ubuntu 12.04 on a Mac with unbootable Mac OS X

Tags: system-installation, mac

I read that installing Ubuntu on Macs does something bad with some efi (?) thing so it get unusable. But my Mac can't boot off Mac OS X, so I can't fix it and install Ubuntu. What do I do?

Comment: Oh and i can boot 2 single user mode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Any recent version** of Ubuntu should not harm (or in any way modify) your Mac's EFI firmware. To give more details or absolute assurance about claims to the contrary, it would of course be necessary to detail and cite the claims (with a link if possible).

However, what you're probably thinking of [is this](https://askubuntu.com/a/130168/22949). Fortunately, [that only affected Ubuntu 11.04](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFIBooting#Caution_for_Mac_owners) (which is [not even supported anymore](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases#End_of_Life_.28EOL.29)), and [has been fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-release-notes/+bug/774089) (and the fix shipped with every subsequent version's installation images, starting with 11.10). Therefore, **there is almost certainly no need to be concerned anymore** (unless you're trying to install from old 11.04 images for some reason).

---

There is one significant Mac EFI related issue with Ubuntu, but it is not dangerous and doesn't pose a threat to your computer. Often a Mac is unable to boot a CD/DVD or live USB created from the regular Ubuntu ISO image because Macs are incompatible with boot media that are set up to work with both BIOS and UEFI (multi-catalog media).

If that's the problem you're having, the solution is to use the special Ubuntu disk image made for Macs. Macs can boot Mac EFI or regular BIOS, so this image removes UEFI support, and can be booted on Macs.

That critical, dangerous, and fortunately **fixed** bug used to be one of the reasons to make sure to use the special Mac image. Now that it's fixed, the special Mac image is still more likely to work than the regular one, but the regular image is not dangerous.

*See [this excellent answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/40480/22949) for a detailed explanation and technical information about the difference between the regular and Mac ISO images.*

This applies only to 64-bit ISO images, so if you're using the 32-bit image, then your problem is different.

Assuming you're trying to install the 64-bit version of Ubuntu on your Mac, the special Mac ISO image for Ubuntu 12.04 LTS [can be downloaded here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.2/release/).

- Specifically, here's [a direct link to the ISO file](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.2/release/ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64+mac.iso).
- And if you want to download via bittorrent, [here's a link to the .torrent file](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.2/release/ubuntu-12.04.2-desktop-amd64+mac.iso.torrent).

That page also contains links to download the text-based alternate CD image, if you want that. (It shouldn't be necessary though, unless you have [highly specialized requirements](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/12.04.2/release/).)

More generally, for people looking for other versions: The special 64-bit Mac ISO images are currently kept [on the cdimage.ubuntu.com download server, categorized by version](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/). (In particular, images for 13.04, the latest stable release as of the time of this writing, [are here](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/13.04/release/).)

Comment: (This is still me) nah, im booted from the cd, i just wonder if installing corrupts my <insert name for mac bios here>

Comment: @aam That seems unlikely, but in order for anyone to answer that, you'll have to provide more information on what you read and where you read it. Including a link, if possible. I recommend editing your question to include this information.

Comment: Actualy im using the 32 bit on a old macbook pro, more info needed? The source was from some random ask ubuntu thread i dont remeber the name of, and i was browsing in inkontogiro mode T_T

Comment: @aam Based on the information that it was an Ask Ubuntu post, I've looked into the matter further, found the post, and confirmed that *there was once a serious issue.* Fortunately it was fixed some time ago. I've expanded my answer for details. (It turns out the original part of the answer is still somewhat relevant, but the primary part is new, and I've put it at the top.)

Comment: It seems that 13.04 or newer does not have any Mac-specific Intel ISOs there. I see only PowerPC, ARM and other stuff but nothing to use on Intel Macs. Also I can confirm that making an USB boot disk from 13.10 original sever media doesn't work on mac, the installer starts but blocks after you choose the language.

Comment: @SorinSbarnea Are you still having this problem? (Sorry for my delay in responding.) If so, I recommend posting a new question about it.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try "VMWare Fusion" & run Ubuntu as Virtual Machine ( VM ) in your mac.
There are restrictions for sure but its easy setup & you don't need to change anything in your beloved Mac. So chances of anything going wrong is Nill.

Through it gives you option to have only 1 GB RAM for the Ubuntu but its Super Fast.
Ubuntu Booting takes around 15/20 Seconds.

Resizing Windows are fast
Full Screen is Good and support the Native Screen Resolution  ( Which Virtual Box don't )
I have Win 8 installed as another VM and it too works like charm.
Copy Paste from Mac works very well.
I almost feel like I am working on a Linux Box.

I have written a detailed Pros & Cons [here](http://madwithmac.blogspot.in/2015/07/run-ubuntu-windows-8-in-mac.html)