# unable to change and edit my hard-drives partitions

Tags: partitioning

I have got 130 gigabytes of my 500 gigabyte mac hard-drive partitioned for ubuntu i can't edit the partitions right now. If i was to uninstall ubuntu, would i be able to use/edit the 130gb that was partitioned?

Answer (score 1):

You can actually edit partitions without ubuntu uninstall by, for example, [gparted](http://gparted.org/)

EDIT: you can also install Gparted from the basic repositary, from Software Center or by `sudo apt-get install gparted`

Comment: i downloaded Gparted but i don't think its for mac.

Comment: After you have Ubuntu installed you can (if needed) edit partitons from there. It is also possible to edit partitions by booting from media containing GParted Live.

Comment: possibly duplicates [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/130142/can-i-install-safely-ubuntu-on-my-mac)

Answer (score 0):

if your hard drive still mounted you will not be able to UN-mount it then you can people always to UN mount be for editing