# Unable to create partitions on a newly bought HDD

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

When I tried to create partition using *"Disks"* software, I got the error, that I have not enough free space in computer.

[image: Image of error]

I have also uploaded a [video on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llNionRAhAE&feature=youtu.be) to explain my problem deeper. I'm using Ubuntu 19.04.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unable to change and edit my hard-drives partitions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/466308/unable-to-change-and-edit-my-hard-drives-partitions)

Comment: Could not tell for sure, but it looked like you tried to format drive, then partition? You may need to zero out first sector, if you did that.

Answer (score 1):

you should probably not be using "Disks" to attempt to partition your HDD. Disks is a simple mountpoint management tool which is really handy in it's own cases but not for formatting.

Gparted is unanimously regarded as the go-to formatting and partitioning tool on linux.

You can find Gparted in you Software Center.

In Gparted, every action yo take needs to be "applied" so be sure to click that green check mark to see your changes take effect!

Also don't choose MBR (in the video I can see your drive is only 1TB not 2TB, so MBR should function for this drive yet this technology, the way I see it, is outdated).

You should choose GPT. GPT replaces MBR and is far better. Most importantly it absolves you of the need to have master and slave partitions. you can have as many primary partitions as you want (128 to be exact) and in no particular order.

from : https://www.disk-partition.com/gpt-mbr/gpt-guid-partition-table-disk-1203.html

> Compare with MBR partitioning style, GPT disk has more advantages. It
>   allows each disk to have up to 128 primary partitions, and the maximum
>   volume size can grow up to 18 petabytes, allowing using primary and
>   backup partition table for redundancy. Also, it supports each GPT
>   partition to have a unique identification ID (GUID). However, the
>   maximum volume size supported by MBR disk is only 2 TB (terabytes) and
>   each disk can only has at most 4 primary partitions (or 3 primary
>   partition + 1 extended partition, in this way unlimited logical
>   partitions can be created on extended partition). In addition, unlike
>   the MBR disk, the crucial platform operation data are stored in
>   partitions but not in the unpartitioned place or hidden sector. In
>   addition, GPT disk district have a surplus of primary and backup
>   partition table to improve the integrity of regional data structure.